# Creating a 3D map out of blocks

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

For my game that I'm creating, I want to make a map out of blocks, much like minecraft. It won't be randomly generated and it wont be infinite. It's going to be very basic, but large. Are there any good programs out there that can help me with this? I'm looking for something simple really. The idea is to make the map 500x500 blocks to start with, and keep putting blocks on top of each other to create the mountains and hills.
The other thing is, the block type will definitely matter within the game. You'll be able to destroy pieces of the mountain, so I'd have to figure out how to create properties for the blocks within the code

Comment: I found a program for minecraft called MCEdit which has what I'm looking for, utility and UI wise. Its simple and does the trick

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the techcraft engine http://techcraft.codeplex.com - its an XNA based minecraft style engine which will give you a good idea of how to handle drawing and storing a map.

Comment: Ive seen that but my map wont be infinite or random. If I could figure out how to make the map by importing a text file thatd be perfect

Comment: Techcraft stores its blocks in a series of Chunks. Though it doesn't come with import/export its pretty trivial to write.
Look in Chunk.cs  for the layout of each chunk its just a big array of Blocks and ChunkManager.cs for  how the chunks relate to each other. 
MCEdit will save in Minecraft format - you can read this in c# using substrate if you want to import that the TechCraft https://code.google.com/p/substrate-minecraft/
Being Infinite or Random isn't relevant here.